# converting COAX to phone for ADSL

Tags: router, modem, adsl

I have a modem that uses COAX as the data line, recently I changed the provider and they said that the internet is ready. They provided a DSL modem that uses phone jack.

Can I cut the coax and connect the inner copper and the shield to phone cable and plug it into new modem?

In the first picture is the back of old modem that uses the coax connection. Then there is a kind of splitter box from new modem, next picture is the manual of the new modem but there is nothing about a coax cable.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Who gave -1 ? be brave and reason. Whats wrong with my question? you people piss me off!

Comment: I wasn't the person who issued the downvote but the question seems to have not been researched.  There are hundreds of articles explaining the difference between cable internet and DSL/ADSL based internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coax is likely a cable modem.  Cablr modems talk DOCSIS, not DSL, so it would not work. I am sure they are electrically incompatible as well (i.e., I do believe cable modems and DSL work on different voltages, impedances, etc.)

What the DSL provider should have done in addition to providing you a DSL box is give you a number of filters.  You need to put one on eaxh jack EXCEPT the one you want to connect the DSL box to.  You'll actually hear the DSL over the landline phone if you pick up a phone not connected to a filter.  Looks like from the picture that the splitter you have has a filter on one jack.  You can connect a landline phone to the filtered jack and the DSL modem on the unfiltered jack.  In this way your landline phone and DSL modem can share a single wall jack.

Answer (score 0):

I know theres already an answer to it but I think you can, I do a little bit of network admin stuff myself and really your questions a bit vague but i may have answer to both...
After looking at the dsl modem and connection that i tore apart :) HEHEHE they actually seem to be using the cable connection that say a brighthouse timewarner company would use the wiring that runs to the pole is 1 wire and its been running to my house for more than 10 years.. It looks like they left that alone took it, plugged it into there converter type box and voila DSL. I wouldnt be suprised if brighthouse has a monopoly on the market there huge in fl.. The only competitor is at&t and they only offer DSL which is stuck at 800KBPS which i think is BS, they say they dont get the same bandwith because of wiring, its just 2 strand thin copper wire. To me that and cable use the same gauge wiring it looks like... But for your router you should be able to rig it to recieve signal You would just have to configure your router by checking your I.P. and having certain ISP info.... I know theyre saying they dont use the same language but they do... 
Article on how dsl works... They use a Fiber optic cable which is the same as the cable companies its just they use different methods of sending the packets, the fiber cable is broken down and distributed to an entire neighborhood which services up to 200 some odd houses which then goes to every house whether they have service or not.

In all dont feel bad for asking a question. If you dont get an answer thats very satisfying people just havent did any research or dont know in general so they can eat a big fat one. lol. But if you were tryna splice it make like a converter type thing like coax to ethernet idk how its setup but most likely wouldnt work. however tele signal to coax into the cable modem I think so its more a question of how to configure the router.

Best thing to do is drop DSL screw Cable, try satellite internet Most places D.L. N U.L. speeds crap on both cable and dsl! Good luck hopefully I answered more questions than i raised lol

AT&T’s popular U-verse system uses VDSL2. It sends video signals by fiber to a neighborhood DSLAM and then distributes the signal to homes over the installed UTP wiring. The U-verse system provides cable TV-like service with IPTV as well as VoIP and Internet access."